# AngularJS Filter-- two filters with an 'or' relationship

Tags: angularjs

Just wondering: in AngularJS, is there a native way to filter such that it has an 'or' relationship instead of the 'and' ?

for example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="account in accounts | filter1 *OR* filter2 *OR* filter3" >
```

so if any of the filters match, it returns that object. As of right now, all three have to pass in order for it to show up.

Thanks a lot,
Y

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom filter.  It could accept the names of other filters and check each one of them to see if each item in the `accounts` array is a valid match against any of the filters.  The following example shows kind of the idea, thought I haven't actually run the code to see if it works, so forgive me for any typos:

```
app.filter('anyOf', function($filter) {
    return function(){
        var array = arguments[0];
        var result = [];
        angular.forEach(array, function(item){
            for(var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++){
                var filter = $filter(arguments[i]);
                if(filter([item]).length){
                    result.push(item);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
});
```

And then you would use it like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="account in accounts | anyOf:'filter1':'filter2':'filter3'" >
```

I think it should work, though its not very efficient because its taking every item in the input array and checking it against any of the filters.  But that might work if your accounts array wasn't super long.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $filter to call filters in your own code, so you can pass the filter names as arguments to a new filter to merge the results [(JSFIDDLE)](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/WrPB5/1).

```
app.filter('merge', function($filter) {
    return function(input, extra) {
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            angular.forEach($filter(arguments[i])(input), function(item) {
                if (result.indexOf(item) < 0) {
                    result.push(item);
                }
            });
        }
        return result;
    };
});
```

And you can pass arguments to your filter like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items|merge:'color':'rating'">
        {{item.rating}}: {{item.color}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

If you wanted to pass arguments to the filter you're merging, you could parse them yourself in the merge filter:

```
<h3>Merge brown and rating >= 5</h3>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items|mergeWithArgs:['color','brown']:['rating',5]">
        {{item.rating}}: {{item.color}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Code:

```
app.filter('mergeWithArgs', function($filter) {
    return function(input) {
        console.dir(arguments);
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var params = arguments[i];
            var filter = $filter(params[0]);
            // remove filter name, prepend input
            params.splice(0, 1, input);
            angular.forEach(filter.apply(this, params), function(item) {
                if (result.indexOf(item) < 0) {
                    result.push(item);
                }
            });
        }
        return result;
    };
});
```